# How do I load only a specific folder on google colab?

Tags: python, directory, mount, google-colaboratory, drive

I was trying to load a folder from my drive but while loading it got an error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a977da366961> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import drive
----> 2 drive.mount('content/gdrive/My Drive/kaggle')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms)
     69 
     70   if ' ' in mountpoint:
---> 71     raise ValueError('Mountpoint must not contain a space.')
     72 
     73   mountpoint = _os.path.expanduser(mountpoint)

ValueError: Mountpoint must not contain a space.
```

How do I get rid of this error. Here is what I have tried :

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('content/gdrive/My Drive/kaggle')
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

Do the authentication as prompted, and then

```
# remember to escape white spaces
%cd /gdrive/My\ Drive/name_of_your_folder_in_drive
```

Comment: please read the question, I am talking about loading the specific folder on drive and not changing directory to reach that folder later

Comment: I was looking for the same thing my self, and this is the only solution I could find. If you are trying to mount any further than gdrive/, you will get this error.

Can I ask what you more specifically wish to do, since this solution won't suffice?

Comment: @MalteJensen At least for me, this solution won't suffice because of security considerations. I don't want to give access to my whole Drive to the software I download and run on Colab

Comment: Bump. A malicious notebook could delete or exfiltrate all your files in an instant and hide the command in scrollable whitespace.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use spaces in the path name, so try to type "Mydrive" instead of "My drive"

```
drive.mount('content/gdrive/MyDrive/kaggle')
```

or simply :

1. Click on the folder icon in the left bar
2. Click on the third icon in the top of this window that showing up, it will allow you to mount your drive automatically

After those steps, you are able to navigate into the needed folder by using
`! cd /folder(or path)` you can also use `pwd` to show your absolute path, `ls` to show the content of the current folder.

Note that `!` is used to activate command prompt code in colab

Comment: My Drive is not something that I created, its there by default and therefore can't change its name too